# Turing reduction from integer factorization to clique

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request

Is there a general web repository of reductions between and among various NP problems?  In particular, I'm looking for a direct Turing reduction from integer factorization (candidate for NP-Intermediate, not known to be NP-Complete) to clique (NP-Complete).

Apologies if this is below the difficulty threshold for cstheory;  I'm a graduate mechanical engineering student by training, so my google whispering skills and resources are somewhat limited (though I am ordering a copy of Arora and Barak!).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that Integer factorization is not known to be NP-complete (so you'll not find it in the repository if it exists)? In every case a "direct natural" reduction from integer factorization to clique seems quite hard; you should use intermediate steps: from integer factorization to SAT then from SAT to 3SAT and finally from 3SAT to Clique.

Comment: Here's a good starting point for reductions between NP-complete problems:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp's_21_NP-complete_problems .  I don't know if there's a natural reduction straight from factorization to clique; there are reductions other than the Cook-Levin one from factorization to SAT, I just don't remember quite how to do that reduction right now.

Comment: Marzio:  Thanks for the advice!  factorization to SAT to 3SAT to Clique provides a path if no direct route can be tracked down.  Also, I edited the question to reflect the fact that I'm looking for factorization to clique, and not the reverse, since that would be kind of a big deal if someone dropped that here! 

Apologies if I'm out of order!

Comment: Marzio:  It was very straight forward to find all of the steps in the reduction chain.  Thanks again!

Comment: not exactly the same but as MdB points out a connection that has been studied quite a bit is factoring→SAT & have lots of links on that. SAT works well as a "hub" type NP complete problem such that many problems can be reduced to it and it can be reduced to many problems (wrt actual "direct" reductions).

Comment: Is this question related to the recent arXiv article: [A Polynomial Time Solution to the Clique Problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.1178) :-)

Comment: LOL, no!  :)  However, thanks to your advice I now have a tool chain now that lets me turn small semiprimes into DIMACs clique files that can be attacked with a solver in a kind-of-acceptable amount of time; maybe they could use it to crack an RSA number and put it beyond doubt!